# crear nuevo objeto con map

Tags: firebase, map

Estoy tratando de crear un objeto totalmente nuevo con la respuesta que me trae la data desde firebase.

como ejemplo esto es la data de firebase:

```
"productos" : {
    "-M4pCGMVNNgxTXe0xo34" : { 
      "category" : "libros",
      "banner" : "{\"H3tag\":\"40%\",\"P1tag\":\"Descuento\", \"H4tag\":\"Para Libros en Diciembre\"}",
      "url" : "somos-polvo-de-estrellas"
},

   "-M4pCGMVNNgxOYi0so90" : { 
      "category" : "revistas",
      "banner" : "{\"H3tag\":\"10%\",\"P1tag\":\"Descuento\", \"H4tag\":\"Para Revistas en Enero\"}",
      "url" : "revista-moda-coleccion"
}
```

recibo la respuesta desde el servicio a mi typescript de esta forma:

```
this.productosService.getData().pipe(
      map((resp: Productos[]) => resp.map( ({category, banner, url}) => ({category, banner, url}) ))
    )
    .subscribe(resp => {

      if(resp){

        resp.forEach(element => {

         let cat = element.category;

         let banner = JSON.parse(element.banner);

         let url = element.url;
          
        
        })
      
      }
 
    });
```

al hacer un console.log(banner); y obtengo esto:

```
Object { "H3tag": "40%", "P1tag": "Disccount", "H4tag": "Para Libros en Diciembre"}

Object { "H3tag": "10%", "P1tag": "Disccount", "H4tag": "Para Revistas en Enero"}
```

hasta ahí creo que todo bien, pero no se como incluir en un arreglo las otras propiedades como son category y url para que un objeto nuevo quede de esta forma:

```
Object { "category" : "libros", "H3tag": "40%", "P1tag": "Disccount", "H4tag": "Para Libros en Diciembre", "url" : "somos-polvo-de-estrellas"}

Object { "category" : "revistas", "H3tag": "10%", "P1tag": "Disccount", "H4tag": "Para Revistas en Enero", "url" : "revista-moda-coleccion"}
```

Alguna idea que me ayude lograr esto por favor?
espero se comprenda... saludos.!

Comment: Por qué esos campos no vienen en la respuesta?

Comment: a que te refieres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con incluir la sentencia `JSON.parse(...)` dentro del `.map()` y utilizar el [spread Operator '...'](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) para combinar los campos.

```
this.productosService.getData().pipe(
  map((resp: Productos[]) => resp.map( ({category, banner, url}) => ({category, ...JSON.parse(banner), url}) ))
)
.subscribe(resp => {
  if(resp){
    resp.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element) // el objeto banner mergeado con las otras keys
    })
  }
});
```

Cuidado que usando el operador puedes sobreescribir llaves cuando los nombres de éstos se repitan entre el objeta que estás 'spredeando' y el objeto resultante que recibe el 'spread'

Comment: wooo es perfecto. muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Gracias!!